# g++ optimizing lowercase to uppercase - bug?

Tags: c++, serial-port

I'm encountering a very strange problem using g++ 4.1.2. I have a very basic program that opens a serial port and writes data to it. The port is opened & setup using following commands:

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

struct termios port_settings;

cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B115200);
cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B115200);

port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);
```

I have an array of `char` consisting of ASCII constants to be sent over the serial link. Data is written using a straightforward `write(fd, &serial_out, 1)`, `serial_out` being the character to be written. This data is then put onto a 16x2 LCD.

Now here's the strange thing. As long as I compile with `-O0` this all works great. However, if I compile with anything higher (1, 2, 3 or s), all the lowercase characters appear as uppercase on the LCD.

Has anyone got any idea what might be causing this? I might be overlooking something simple, but I really have no clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are basically setting the terminal parameters to random values.

To get more meaningful behavior, first interrogate the serial port's settings and then change the items as you see fit:

```
struct termios port_settings;
if (tcgetattr (fd, &port_settings) != 0)
            return -1;

cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B115200);
cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B115200);

port_settings.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB|CSTOPB|CSIZE);
port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);
```

Comment: That seems to make sense. Will test tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

The question you have to ask yourself is whether `serial_out` has the correct value at the point it is passed to `write()`, thereafter it is in the library call, and the optimisation level of the compilation unit will have no affect.

Most changes in behaviour between optimised and unoptimised code are due to use *undefined* or *implementation defined* compiler behaviour, which may change between different compilation settings. The code you probably need to show here as all that relating to the variable `serial_out` rather than the port configuration.

Ideally, use your debugger to inspect the value when `write()` is called, though that can sometimes be difficult to follow with optimised code, and you may need to resort to inspecting registers for variables that have been optimised away.